# Do fats in edible oils and ghee undergo oxidation or rancidation when cooked in pressure cooker along with rice?

Tags: organic-oxidation, fats

In a lot of dishes, it's quite common to cook rice along with fats like edible oil or ghee(clarified butter), in a pressure cooker.

Now the pressure cooker can reach very high temperatures, to quickly cook the rice. But can this degrade and oxidize the oil and ghee?

Comment: Pressure cookers don't reach "very high" temperatures. A typical home pressure cooker reaches about 100 kPa above ambient atmospheric pressure. At 200 kPa, the boiling point of water is about 120 °C. Most effects happen at higher temperatures, like the Maillard reaction (~150 °C), oil smoke points (~200 °C).

Comment: @Nayuki thank you, but does the high pressure of 200kpa influence fat oxidation and rancidity?

Comment: @Nayuki so while cooking oil and ghee in pressure cooker can we assume that the structure is not so changed and its health impact is as before?

Comment: not sure, but the 2 times I tried rice cooked in pressure cooker with ghee given me very hard time (feeling of indigestion/fullness/discomfort/belches all the time and dullness for almost 48 hours). not sure what might be the reason or it's just a coincidence, I won't try again :)

Comment: By the semiempirical Van't Hoff rule, speed of chemical reactions increases typically 2-4 times by temperature increase by 10 deg C. There is no threshold temperature limit below which reactions do not happen. But there are conditional threshold limits below which reaction rate can be neglected. That is the case for pressure cooking.